# Creating Diagonal Pattern in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create diagonal hatch pattern in WPF. I am using following XAML code to generate it:

```xml
  <VisualBrush 
  x:Key="HatchBrushnew" 
  TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,30,30" 
  ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,30,30"    
  ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Canvas>

                <Path  Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.1cm" >
                    <Path.Data>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="30,30" />
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>

            </Canvas>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
```

But the after filling shape with this pattern, I am getting small gap between two lines. Can anyone suggest a way to avoid that small gap?

[image: Generate Output]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `DrawingBrush` would be much simpler than a `VisualBrush`.

In addition to the central diagonal line, this one draws two additional lines (which may of course be shorter) to cover the top right and bottom left corners of the Brush tile:

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="HatchBrush" TileMode="Tile"
              Viewport="0,0,30,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
              Viewbox="0,0,30,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="5"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <Geometry>M0,0 L30,30 M15,-15 L45,15 M-15,15 L15,45</Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

---

As shown in the answer given by Balázs, you may also set the Brush's `Transform` property, and use e.g. a single vertical `LineGeometry`:

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="HatchBrush" TileMode="Tile"
              Viewport="0,0,30,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
              Viewbox="0,0,30,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.Transform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
    </DrawingBrush.Transform>
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="5"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,15" EndPoint="30,15"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `VisualBrush.Transform`:

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="HatchBrushnew" 
  TileMode="Tile"
  Viewport="0,0,30,30" 
  ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
  Viewbox="0,0,30,30"    
  ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <VisualBrush.Transform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
    </VisualBrush.Transform>
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
      <Canvas>
        <Path  Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.1cm" >
          <Path.Data>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="15,0" EndPoint="15,30" />
          </Path.Data>
        </Path>
      </Canvas>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
  </VisualBrush>
```

And the result is:

[image]

This appears a bit more sparse, you could play around with the values of `VisualBrush.Viewport` to fix that. Since we are rotating 135 degrees, the spacing is in fact sqrt(2) times larger than the original one, you could use it as a hint.

Comment: This solution is simple but effective! I played around a while with a diagonal tile always having the breaks at the tile corners. Thank You @Balázs

Answer (score 1):

Here the coded variant to @Balázs solution (in VB)

```
    Public ReadOnly Property fill As Brush
        Get
            Dim FillColor As Color
            Dim HatchThickness As Double
            Dim HatchAngle As Double

            FillColor = Colors.Black
            HatchThickness = 3
            HatchAngle = 45

            '
            ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667566/creating-diagonal-pattern-in-wpf
            ' and
            ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-brushes-overview#paint-with-a-drawing
            '
            Dim myBrush As New DrawingBrush()

            Dim myGeometryGroup As New GeometryGroup()

            '
            ' add a horizontal line to the geometry group
            '
            myGeometryGroup.Children.Add(New LineGeometry(New Windows.Point(0, 0), New Windows.Point(10, 0)))

            '
            ' draw geometry with transparent brush and pen as defined
            '
            Dim p As New Windows.Media.Pen
            p.Brush = New SolidColorBrush(FillColor)
            p.Thickness = HatchThickness
            p.StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Square
            p.EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Square

            Dim myDrawing As New GeometryDrawing(Nothing, p, myGeometryGroup)

            '
            ' apply the drawing to the brush
            '
            myBrush.Drawing = myDrawing

            '
            ' in case, there is more than one line use a Drawing Group
            '

            'Dim myDrawingGroup As New DrawingGroup()
            'myDrawingGroup.Children.Add(checkers)
            'myBrush.Drawing = myDrawingGroup

            ' set viewbox and viewport
            myBrush.Viewbox = New Windows.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10)
            myBrush.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute
            myBrush.Viewport = New Windows.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10)
            myBrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute
            myBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile
            myBrush.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill
            ' rotate
            myBrush.Transform = New RotateTransform(HatchAngle)

            Return myBrush

        End Get
    End Property
```

and in C#

```
public Brush fill
{
    get
    {
        Color FillColor;
        double HatchThickness;
        double HatchAngle;

        FillColor = Colors.Black;
        HatchThickness = 3;
        HatchAngle = 45;

        // 
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667566/creating-diagonal-pattern-in-wpf
        // and
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-brushes-overview#paint-with-a-drawing
        // 
        DrawingBrush myBrush = new DrawingBrush();

        GeometryGroup myGeometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();

        // 
        // add a horizontal line to the geometry group
        // 
        myGeometryGroup.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Windows.Point(0, 0), new Windows.Point(10, 0)));

        // 
        // draw geometry with transparent brush and pen as defined
        // 
        Windows.Media.Pen p = new Windows.Media.Pen();
        p.Brush = new SolidColorBrush(FillColor);
        p.Thickness = HatchThickness;
        p.StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Square;
        p.EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Square;

        GeometryDrawing myDrawing = new GeometryDrawing(null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */, p, myGeometryGroup);

        // 
        // apply the drawing to the brush
        // 
        myBrush.Drawing = myDrawing;

        // 
        // in case, there is more than one line use a Drawing Group
        // 

        // Dim myDrawingGroup As New DrawingGroup()
        // myDrawingGroup.Children.Add(checkers)
        // myBrush.Drawing = myDrawingGroup

        // set viewbox and viewport
        myBrush.Viewbox = new Windows.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        myBrush.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
        myBrush.Viewport = new Windows.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        myBrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
        myBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
        myBrush.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
        // rotate
        myBrush.Transform = new RotateTransform(HatchAngle);

        return myBrush;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real reason you have that edged end is because your drawing the line at 0,0 and it naturally creates 2 90 degree angles.

Had you drawn the lines starting at (0,30) to (15,30) it would be straight edged.  Then rotate the line 90 degrees.