# Brush pattern in c# wpf (xaml - vector)

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, brush

I need to draw on canvas using a few brush patterns like "Paint" in Windows OS.
I need "oil brush" and "pastel".
As I understand, it's possible via VisualBrush.Visual (Canvas with vector paths).

```
<UserControl x:Class="DrawingToolbar.DTBrushParamsContainer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DrawingToolbar"
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="395" d:DesignWidth="500">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <VisualBrush 
            x:Key="OilBrush" 
            TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,10,10" 
            ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,10,10"    
            ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas Width="495.9968" Height="66.6656" ClipToBounds="True" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="55" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <xctk:ColorCanvas x:Name="colorCanvas" Grid.Row="0" 
                          Background="Transparent"
                          Height="145" Width="237"
                          UsingAlphaChannel="False" Margin="0,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="Цвет кисти:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
        <Label Content="Толщина кисти:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Margin="242,176,0,0"/>
        <Slider x:Name="brushSizeSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" Maximum="100"/>
        <Label Content="Прозрачность цвета кисти:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Margin="0,176,0,0"/>
        <Slider x:Name="transparencySlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" Maximum="255"/>
        <Label Content="Стиль кисти:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Margin="242,0,0,0"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="normalBrush_rb" Content="Обычная кисть" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="oilBrush_rb" Content="Кисть для масла" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="pastelBrush_rb" Content="Пастель" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <InkCanvas x:Name="normalBrush_ink" 
            Background="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="242,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248">

        </InkCanvas>

        <InkCanvas x:Name="oilBrush_ink" 
            Background="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="242,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248">

            <Line X1="10" X2="100" Y1="15" Y2="15" Visibility="Visible" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="{StaticResource OilBrush}">
            </Line>

        </InkCanvas>

        <InkCanvas x:Name="pastelBrush_ink" 
            Background="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="242,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"/>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In my app, I need to draw line on canvas with pattern (sample for user) and to draw, using this pattern, by mouse.

Can you help me with drawing, using brush pattern (step-by-step) in xaml and|or programmatically? It can be vector in xaml or image file using.

[Brush pattern (.eps)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdsjfj5xn1cleys/brush_oil.eps?dl=0)

[Brush pattern (.svg)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y46k83dmw23lzjn/brush_oil.svg?dl=0)

[Source link of brush](https://www.rawpixel.com/image/582016/blue-paint-brush-stroke)

[Brush pattern (.xaml)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8uiqou3cn7a9wyj/brush_oil.xaml?dl=0)

Now, I draw in xaml, using Brush pattern, but this is not oil brush (like in default paint app):

[image]

Comment: DrawingBrush might be simpler than VisualBrush: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42668028/1136211

Comment: @Clemens May be, but anyway I need to declare GeometryDrawing.Geometry. As you see, SVG or EPS are very big files and after converting to xaml, it's not working, because default size of brush is very big

Comment: I was append xaml-file with this brush