# How to implement XIPattern enum in wpf

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

My app is mimicking the excel cell style dialog, down to the pattern style for the fill. The control we are using is a collection of Telerik RadMenuItem's and we set the color, font, font style, etc. in the RadMenuItem. I'm trying to get the 75% gray fill and I know the enum value, but what kind of brush do I apply it to? I can't find any info on this.

Comment: In case you are asking for a hatch pattern brush, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42668028/1136211

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing what you want, which is possible.

Use a solidcolorbrush and your color enum.

if your enum isn't a color then you will need to find the equivalent gray hex value.

if by 75% you mean opacity you can set opacity on a solid color brush.

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.75" />
```

for more info see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-brushes-overview#common-brush-features)

for more info on excel colors see this [article](https://peltiertech.com/using-colors-in-excel/)

for the xlpattern you want to use a TileBrush, more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-different-tile-patterns-with-a-tilebrush)

Comment: Gee, could it be this simple? Let me give this a try. I appreciate you getting back to me so quickly.

Comment: No, that's too simple. I don't think I can attach a screen shot from excel, but it is the styles that you see on the top row of fill patterns. There is a pattern there, not just the gray.

Comment: ah, what you want then is a TileBrush, or System.Windows.Media.TileBrush. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-different-tile-patterns-with-a-tilebrush.